# Error using buildozer to build android package for kivy project

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, aidl, buildozer

When using buildozer to build android package for kivy project, this error occurs:

```
command failed: "aidl cannot be executed, ..."
```

In addition, in the directory of the kivy project, a file named `invalid encoding` has been created.

What's the reason for the error? I think maybe the encoding error. But how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. If I remember well, you need to install 'Android SDK tools', 'Android SDK Platforms-tools' and API 19 from the Android SDK Manager. Open a terminal : `cd $HOME/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools` (maybe the version of your Android SDK is different than 20) then
`./android sdk`

Once it's done, you should be able to generate your APK file using `buildozer android debug`.